# ASP.NET mvc -url text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a website, by default it will be www.forums.com.   It will load the default route ie.Controller = "Home", action = "Index".

My requirement is.

I have to load the same Controller and action, but Url should be display as "www.forums.com/Community" .  It should display the same content as in /Home/Index.

when they click the Home Button image after navigating to some other pages, it should still load the "www.forums.com/Community".

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: You really can't change the browser's URL, unless you send a redirect.  Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement clearly states you to update the action name to `Community` and default route action to `Community`, instead of `Index`.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Community", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Home Controller

```
public ActionResult Community
{
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what he's trying to do, as far as I can tell.

Comment: The requirement clearly states that clicking the home button also needs to navigate to this Url, so there is no point in keeping the index action.

Comment: His requirement clearly states that the URL should *display* /Community... not the same thing.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I understand! unless there is a need of Home/Index action result to be used from some where, this can be achieved by the way I mentioned.This can be achieved from a custom route also, but looks like we are over thinking, I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, it will work.
no need to change in controller only add this code in route config. Above default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Index",
            url: "Community",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```